# How do I easily parse a URL with parameters in a Rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, url, parsing

I have a some code that embeds a `return_to` URL into a redirect (like OpenID) that I want to test:

```
def test_uses_referrer_for_return_to
  expected_return_to = 'http://test.com/foo'
  @request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = expected_return_to
  get :fazbot
  # @response.redirected_to looks like http://service.com?...&return_to=[URI-encoded version of URL above]&...
  encoded_return_to = (something_here)[:return_to]
  assert_equal expected_return_to, URI.unencode(encoded_return_to)
end
```

It's a Rails `ActionController::TestCase`, so I have access to all sorts of helper methods; I just can't find the right one.

Of course I could use `URI.parse` to get the params part of the URL, then split it on `/&|?/` and then split again on `'='`, but I'm hoping this is already done for me.  Plus, what if I miss some obscure rule in URL escaping or parameter parsing?  There *has* to be something in `ActionPack` or `ActiveSupport` to do this, but I can't find it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`CGI::parse(querystring)` will parse a querystring into a hash. Then, `CGI::unescape(string)` will undo any URL-encoding in the value.

Alternatively, you can use `Rack::Utils.parse_query` and `Rack::Utils.unescape` if you're on a recent Rack-based version of Rails, and want to be super-modern.

I'm not aware of any Rails-specific helper methods that wrap these utility functions, but they're pretty simple to use, and CGI or Rack is already loaded in the Rails environment anyway.

Comment: CGI::parse wraps all values in an array. +1 for Rack::Utils.parse_query

Comment: CGI::parse handles bad characters you sometimes see in URLs, rack parse_query will fail on {,},',", ...

Comment: If you have nested query, give it a try to `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(q)`: `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query 'foo=1&bar%5Bbaz%5D=baz'` => `{"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>{"baz"=>"baz"}}`

Comment: on ruby 2.2 I see `CGI::parse` doing automatic URL decoding so the extra `unescape` can do double the work and in edge cases produce wrong results

Answer (score 29):

You want [Addressable](https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable/) for this.

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/?var=value")
uri.query_values # => {"var"=>"value"}
uri.query_values = {"one" => "1", "two" => "2"}
uri.to_s # => "http://example.com/?two=2&one=1"
```

It'll automatically handle all the escaping rules for you, and it has some other useful features, like not throwing exceptions for perfectly valid but obscure URIs like the built-in URI parser.

Comment: You are biased as the maintainer, I am not and would rather use this then anything else. Wonderful gem, thanks for making it happen.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. It's been quite a few years of hard work building and improving it.

Comment: Addressable is a replacement for the URI implementation that is part of Ruby's standard library. Addressable works in Ruby 1.8.x, 1.9.x, and JRuby.