# How to filter parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering

Rails has built in log filtering so you don't log passwords and credit cards.  Works great for that but when you want to trigger a custom log (like to email) and send your own params or other data along with it, the parameters are obviously not auto-filtered. I have been digging and trying to find this in the rails source but have had no luck so far.

I have configured rails to filter parameters as follows and it works properly for keeping the data out of rails logs:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :credit_card]
```

How would you filter sensitive data from the params hash before dumping it into an email, api call or custom (non-rails) log?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can always use the `except` method:

```
params.except(:password, :password_confirmation, :credit_card)
```

That will exclude them from the listing. To "filter" them you could [try this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152388/manually-filter-parameters-in-rails).

Answer (score 76):

### Rails 4+

Sidenote for filtering the log in Rails 4+: The `config.filter_parameters` has been moved from application.rb to it's own initializer.

**config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

Comment: Documented here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

Answer (score 54):

tadman answered correctly but here is some additional info:

In application.rb

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :credit_card]
```

Wherever you are doing custom logging:

```
f = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)
f.filter :order => {:credit_card => "4111111111111111"}

 => {:order=>{:credit_card=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Comment: It works but the recommended way to do that in Rails Apps are create a initializer file with the filter_parameters method.

Answer (score 22):

If you are inside a rails controller method, why not just call `request.filtered_parameters`?

It is always a good choice to use what is already provided. Cheers!

Comment: This is actually should be the correct answer, thank you :)

Comment: @MohamedSami How would this work? Calling `request.filtered_parameters.delete :fat_param` from the controller method doesn't seem to stop :fat_param from getting logged?

Comment: Thank you, I'm not if I remember why I wrote this? but I think for sure, it helped me somehow, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 4):

Just to add on @tadman answer:

When using [`except`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Except/except), beware that it will remove only top-level keys of your parameters, eg:

```
params = {
  search_query: 'foobar', 
  secret_key1: 'SENSITIVE_KEY_1', 
  auth_info: {secret_key_2: 'SENSITIVE_KEY2'}
}
params.except(:secret_key1, :secret_key2)

=> {:search_query=>"foobar", :auth_info=>{:secret_key_2=>"SENSITIVE_KEY2"}}
```

Using `request.filtered_parameters` will filter both of those keys if they are in config/application.rb

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```