# Simple Form - filtering updated attributes in the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, patch, update-attributes

Simple question about Simple Form:

I've an attribute in a user model for a token I'd like marked as [FILTERED] when passed over the network (as the password field does by default).

e.g.

I have:

```
Parameters: { "token"=>"WYXe3Z24JmUq", "email"=>"test@testing.com", 
"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

I want:

```
Parameters: { "token"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test@testing.com", 
"password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

and an example form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :token %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

What option do I need to add to the field to achieve this? I'm certain there's an option, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in application.rb do the following:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :token]
```

check this answer: [How to filter parameters in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232554/how-to-filter-parameters-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4**

As a side note, `config.filter_paramters` has been moved it it's own initializers.

**config/initializers/filter_paramter_logging.rb**

You need to add the below line of code to filter the `token` and `password`

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

  # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.

  Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password, :token]
```