# Ruby On Rails 4 checkbox returned as filtered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, attr-accessor

In my erb I have:

```
 <td>
 <%= user_field.label :user_password_changed, "Do you wish to change your password?" %>
 <%= user_field.check_box(:user_password_changed) %>
 </td>
```

Related to this field I have Jquery which works fine:

```
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
  var getid = this.id;
  if (getid.includes('user_password_changed')) {
  if (this.checked == true) { $("div#change_password").css("display", "block"); } 
  else { $("div#change_password").css("display", "none");}  
  }   });
```

In the relevant model, User, user_password_changed is not a field.  So I am using attr_accessor, where I have:

```
 attr_accessor :user_password_changed
```

When I post the params are:

```
"user"=>{"role_id"=>"1", "user_changed"=>"1", "user_id"=>"50", "community_name"=>"foo", "username"=>"foo", "user_alias"=>"foo", "user_password_changed"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"foo", "user_type"=>foo}...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is filtered only in logs. It's due to security.

You can customize it like written this: [How to filter parameters in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232554/how-to-filter-parameters-in-rails)

Comment: Thank you.  I see multiple options here.  I would like to structure within the controller, or should I use model.  Which is best?

Comment: False alarm... I can still interrogate param :user_password_changed in controller.  All good