# Parameter filter for password not working (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, filtering

I am creating a logging method in my application controller.  I have the following setup, but for some reason, my parameter filter is not filtering the password.  What is missing? How do I make sure my app is secure and that all the password parameters are being filtered?

***config/applicaton.rb***

```
  # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
  config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

***applicaton controller***

```
  before_filter :record_activity

  def record_activity(note = nil)
      @activity={}
      @activity['user'] = current_user
      @activity['note'] = note
      @activity['browser'] = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
      @activity['ip_address'] = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
      @activity['controller'] = controller_name 
      @activity['action'] = action_name 
      @activity['params'] = log_filter(params.inspect)
      p @activity
  end
```

***OUTPUT IN TERMINAL***

```
    15:39:38 web.1    | 
{"user"=>nil, 
"note"=>nil, 
"browser"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0",
 "ip_address"=>"127.0.0.1", 
"controller"=>"sessions", 
"action"=>"create", 
"params"=>"{\"utf8\"=>\"✓\", \"authenticity_token\"=>\"dYofOQ64sTajNVn2JiJWVM+E3kz5jCGazrYBObukBAQ=\", 
\"user\"=>{\"email\"=>\"user@domain.com\",
 \"password\"=>\"thepasswordexposed\",
 \"remember_me\"=>\"0\"}, 
\"commit\"=>\"Login\", 
\"action\"=>\"create\", 
\"controller\"=>\"sessions\"}"}
```

***EDIT: ***
I've added the following, but it still does not work, any recommendation?

```
  def log_filter(hash)
    filters = Rails.application.config.filter_parameters
    f = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new filters
    f.filter hash
  end
```

***Error on line 36 ...***

```
NoMethodError at /users/sign_in    
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007fa0280b3a68>

36     f.filter hash
```

ANSWER:

My solution was as follows, I needed to remove the .inspect and it started working.

```
  def record_activity(note = nil)
      @activity={}
      @activity['user'] = current_user
      @activity['note'] = note
      @activity['browser'] = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
      @activity['ip_address'] = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
      @activity['controller'] = controller_name 
      @activity['action'] = action_name 
      @activity['params'] = params
      p @activity
  end
```

Comment: Did you restart the rails console?

Comment: yes, but does not work.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `config.filter_parameters` is just for http parameters (which you get then in `params`). It will not work with your own objects.

So if you make a request then in log file you will have some standard information

```
Started GET "/en/projects/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-28 04:13:11 +0700
Processing by ProjectsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"1"}
```

In row with `Parameters` value for password will be filtered it is there.

But if you use `p` or `puts` it will not work.

Here way for [manually filter parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152388/manually-filter-parameters-in-rails)

Comment: I thought my params are http parameters.  What are my params? What would you recommend to correct my issue. thank you

Comment: solution was to just use params, log_filter not even needed.  thank you