# Rails console - TypeError: can't cast Hash to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, console, sqlite3-ruby

A little background first, I was able to get the  - [Angular/Rails project working on local](https://github.com/sectore/CafeTownsend-Angular-Rails)

I went to change the user/password in sqlite3 and here are the steps that I took

```
rails c
a = User.find(1)
a.name = "myName"
a.password_digest = "mySurName"
a.save
```

Great, it worked! NOT

Well, kind of, but the Angular app is looking for a password that looks something like this - $2a$10$TrTjNCWr5KlwW2h9aJr45u8MwLDo2ErEFQp1/ixc.8KW...

After doing some digging,  [I found a stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152388/manually-filter-parameters-in-rails)

Followed by me trying to do the following:

```
a = User.find(1)
filters = Rails.application.config.filter_parameters
f = ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new filters
b = f.filter :password_digest => 'mySurName'
a.password_digest = b
```

Which results in an error that is in the subject line of this post - **TypeError: can't cast Hash to string**, followed by (0.1ms)  rollback transaction and tons of lines of references to .rb files

So, my ultimate question is, how do I update a record that has a filter on a password field, while using rails console?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on password hashing and storage, your password should never be stored as plaintext. Just a hunch, try this instead:

```
a = User.find(1)
a.name = "whatever"
a.password = "something"
a.save
```

In devise (and probably others) a password setter is defined for the User model which automatically stores the hash of the password in the password_digest column.

Comment: That will just store the word "something" - I found the answer, which I will post

Comment: The code you have written in your answer does exactly the same thing as this code, except you create a new user instead of finding a user with id = 1

Comment: oh except I didn't set the password_confirmation field.

Answer (score 0):

OK, while reading another post to something that was somewhat unrelated - here's the answer:

```
a = User.new(:name => "Luke", :password => "Skywalker", :password_confirmation => "Skywalker")
a.save
```

Which creates something like this:

```
password_digest: "$2a$10$OPlc1rCZscqPkFYSp10NQeTmDRNs1iuv6D0VLAKk8sXu..."
```