# rails, how to get params from url string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I easily parse a URL with parameters in a Rails test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916067/how-do-i-easily-parse-a-url-with-parameters-in-a-rails-test)

sorry for my english...

I have in my archives.rb model a method to get all src attributes from a html content, I am getting src's like:

`http://localhost:3000/es/editor/archives/28/show_image?x=142&y=142`

I need to get the params from that url, specifically: **id, x, y**

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score -21, accepted):

It might be done using some regexp for example

```
irb(main):011:0> s = "http://localhost:3000/es/editor/archives/28/show_image?x=142&y=142"
=> "http://localhost:3000/es/editor/archives/28/show_image?x=142&y=142"
irb(main):012:0> s[/.*\/(\d+).+x=(\d+).*y=(\d+)/,1]
=> "28"
irb(main):013:0> s[/.*\/(\d+).+x=(\d+).*y=(\d+)/,2]
=> "142"
irb(main):014:0> s[/.*\/(\d+).+x=(\d+).*y=(\d+)/,3]
=> "142"
irb(main):015:0>
```

Comment: There are so many ways this could fail. Let's not use flaky Regex when robust parsers already exist.

Comment: such a poor answer, use CGI parse as explained in the dup answer link.

Comment: I disagree that my answer is **poor** and DGM's one is **correct** since both approaches depend on a structure of the url, mine to get all three params and DGM's to get and id. Both will fail if the url is different.
I do agree that using CGI to get x and y values looks pretty.

Answer (score 19):

The **correct** approach :

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/es/editor/archives/28/show_image?x=142&y=142"
uri = URI::parse(url)
id = uri.path.split('/')[4]
params = CGI::parse(uri.query)
```

Comment: you forgot about an `id`

Comment: updated to get the id then. :)

Comment: edit was wrong, and the suggested edit to fix it was incorrectly rejected.  I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

In your controller you can do 'params[:x]' and 'params[:y]'. For example:

```
x = params[:x]
y = params[:y]
```

Comment: thanks, but ... I can't do that, first: my code is in a model, and second the url's are string extracted from html text code.