# rails 3.1 Reload a page with a different locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-3.1

I have followed this [beautiful site](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to create internationalization in my site.

However I cannot figure out how to reload a page with a different locale when a user clicks on a language button.

Example:
If the user is here:

```
/es/events/14
```

when user hits English language reload to

```
/en/events/14
```

This is the view:

```
 %li= link_to "eu", change_locale_path(:locale => "eu")
 %li= link_to "es", change_locale_path(:locale => "es")
 %li= link_to "en", change_locale_path(:locale => "en")
 %li= link_to "fr", change_locale_path(:locale => "fr")
```

This the method in ApplicationController

```
def change_locale
 if current_user
   current_user.locale = params[:locale]
   current_user.save
 else
   I18n.locale = params[:locale]
 end
 redirect_to root_url  (this is temporal)
end
```

What should I have instead of redirect_to root_url to reload the page?

Comment: you may return to previous page, see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652084/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-get-the-previous-url/8801313#8801313

Comment: I tried that before, but as far as I remembered loads the page with the old locale, because the locale is in the url

Comment: try to parse url and change params[:locale], see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916067/how-do-i-easily-parse-a-url-with-parameters-in-a-rails-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- [:ru, :ua, :en].each do |locale|
  %li= link_to locale, params.merge(locale: locale)
```